# EXC_BAD_ACCESS calling a function from NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have to say, I'm quite new to objective-c/Cocoa. Currently I'm trying to update some data regularly using a NSTimer.

```
@interface MyAppController : NSObject  
{
    NSTimer * monitorTimer;
    DemoObject *myObj;
}
...
```

and the following implementation:

```
...
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        myObj = [[DemoObject alloc] init];

        monitorTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(monitorTimerFired:) 
                                             userInfo:NULL 
                                              repeats:YES];

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:monitorTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    }

    return self;
}

...

- (void) monitorTimerFired: (id)sender
{               
    BOOL status = [myObj isRunning];
}
```

Calling the monitorTimerFired synchronously, e.g., from the init function works fine. If it is called by the timer it always results in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Obviously it is a problem of memory management, but I just cannot find the proper solution. Any Idea, Comment, Solution? Thanks :)

Comment: Where's the code for the isRunning method?

Comment: What is the lifetime of your MyAppController instance?  How do you terminate the looping of your timer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to store the `NSTimer` in the instance variable `monitorTimer` you should retain and properly invalidate, release, and `nil` (if not in dealloc) it when done.

```
monitorTimer = [[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2
                                        target:self
                                      selector:@selector(monitorTimerFired:) 
                                      userInfo:NULL 
                                       repeats:YES] retain];
```

As for the EXC_BAD_ACCESS your `MyAppController` is likely deallocated by time the timer fires.

Comment: Method `addTimer:forMode:` does not automatically retain timer?

Comment: It does but you should still follow memory management rules. If the OP wants to just `assign` the timer and depend on the run loop retaining thats fine but the timer still needs to be invalidated when the class is deallocated. Also if it were retained `monitorTimer` could check `isValid` without and `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` since on invalidation the timer is removed from the run loop.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Although it was not "necessary" to solve my problem, it lead me to the solution ;). I had a missing retain in the init function of the DemoObject. The bad access was raised in the isRunning function and not in the monitorTimerFired ...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest changing your `monitorTimer` instance variable into a property, e.g.:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *monitorTimer;
```

This way, the proper mem-mgmt is done for you when you try to change your `monitorTimer` in future - just use synthesized setter via `self.monitorTimer = ...`.
Well, don't forget to properly release it in `-dealloc` method. Stop the timer before releasing it by calling `[monitorTimer invalidate]`.

Speaking of stopping timers: in your init method you set your timer to repeat, so make sure you stop it when you don't need it anymore (especially in `-dealloc` as mentioned above!).